# Study about confirmation bias (facial disfigurement and job interviews)

Tags: reference-request

In a youtube video (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/V91kENu5hE8)), Konstantin Kisin talks about a study in which subjects were given fake scars to study how this affects outcomes of job interviews. The participants did not know that the fake scars were removed shortly before the interview ("we just need to brush up the makeup of the scar quickly"). The scars therefore could not have affected the interview directly, but many participants reported they were treated unfairly because of their scars, which points to confirmation bias. Can anyone point me to that study?